# Logitech Ghub won't open or stuck display infinite loading gif

Tags: windows

Sometimes Logitech ghub won't open or display an infinite loading gif. Because of that, macros and profiles not work...

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple method : Task manager

You can kill all ghub instance from your task manager (CTRL SHIFT SUPPR) :

- lghub.exe
- logi_crashpad_handler.exe
- lghub_agent.exe
  [image]

## Second method kill with python

Or you can bind this program to your stream deck / keyboard :

### First

Create a file named **killGhub.pyw** (.py => extension python, .pyw => run python without a visible windows)

### Second

```python
import ctypes
import subprocess

import sys
import time
from _winapi import SW_HIDE


def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except Exception:
        return False


if is_admin():
    subprocess.call("taskkill /T /IM lghub.exe /F", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("taskkill /T /IM logi_crashpad_handler.exe /F", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("taskkill /T /IM lghub_agent.exe /F", shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    subprocess.call('C:\\Program Files\\LGHUB\\lghub.exe', shell=True)
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, SW_HIDE)
```

To kill the updater we need admin right.
Requirement : PYTHON 3

Ps : I use python because it was easier for me to bind this with my keyboard macro, maybe with a classic stream deck you can use just a powershell scripts.